# Prisma - ConnectorError

Tags: mysql, prisma, prisma-graphql, prisma2

I'm trying to learn Prisma on my hobby project so I started with basics.
The first thing I tried was a simple GET request which should list all results in a table.

```
// Using "@prisma/client": "^3.8.1",
const position = await prisma.position.findMany();
```

It worked fine but obviously, I don't have any data so it return an empty array. If I try to add some items to the Position table I'm getting error (mentioned below). Same error I'm getting also from Prisma Studio so I wonder If I did something wrong or what can I do to fix it.

Prisma schema

```
model Position {
  id               Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  name             String         @db.VarChar(255)
  externalId       String         @db.VarChar(255)
  benefits         String         @db.Text()
}
```

MySQL Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `Position` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `externalId` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `benefits` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Query:

```
await prisma.position.create({
  data: {
     name: 'Position Name',
     externalId: '321',
     benefits: 'My benefits',
  },
});
```

Error:

```
  Error occurred during query execution:
ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(Server(ServerError { code: 1064, message: "target: referral.-.primary: vttablet: (errno 1064) (sqlstate 42000) (CallerID: unsecure_grpc_client): Sql: \"insert into Position(`name`, externalId, 
benefits) values (:v1, :v2, :v3)\", BindVars: {}", state: "42000" })) })
    at cb (C:\Develop\referral-nextjs-prisma\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:38695:17)
    at async assetHandler (webpack-internal:///./pages/api/position/index.tsx:12:34)
    at async Object.apiResolver (C:\Develop\referral-nextjs-prisma\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils.js:102:9)
    at async DevServer.handleApiRequest (C:\Develop\referral-nextjs-prisma\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1076:9)
    at async Object.fn (C:\Develop\referral-nextjs-prisma\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:963:37)
    at async Router.execute (C:\Develop\referral-nextjs-prisma\node_modules\next\dist\server\router.js:222:32)
    at async DevServer.run (C:\Develop\referral-nextjs-prisma\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1103:29)
    at async DevServer.run (C:\Develop\referral-nextjs-prisma\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:444:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\Develop\referral-nextjs-prisma\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:319:20) {
  clientVersion: '3.8.1'
}
```

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to be able to replicate your error. Would you kindly consider creating a [bug report](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new/choose) on the Prisma repo, with instructions on how to reproduce the issue? We'll try to identify the problem!

Comment: I found out, the issue was in PlanetScale database. I moved to a different database provider and the same Prisma works fine :)

Comment: Oh cool, glad to hear the issue was solved!

Comment: By the way, if you're looking to use Prisma with Planetscale, here are some resources that might be useful: [The get started guide](https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/start-from-scratch/relational-databases-typescript-planetscale), [Prisma with planetscale docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/using-prisma-with-planetscale), [Issue compiling various problems/workarounds for Planetscale + Prisma](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/7292)